# legend ordering and factor ordering in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have produced the following code:

```
#library(tidyverse)
#library(ggplot2)
#library(forcats)


    temp<-tribble(
 ~kt, ~yes, ~'no', ~'NA',
 "Berne", 47,33, 0,
 "Basel", 60,45,0,
 "Geneva", 64,61,0,
 "Zurich", 19,107,3
)

temp2 <- gather(temp, ' ', val, -kt)
ggplot(temp2, aes(kt, val, fill = ` `)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'fill', color='darkgrey') +
  geom_text(aes(label = val), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), size=3) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x='Jurisdiction', y='Percentage') +
  coord_flip()+ scale_fill_grey(start = 0.9, end = .5) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Witnesses heard"))
```

Now I have the following difficulties and would appreciate it if someone could help me:

- How can I change the ordering of the legend? The ordering should be just reversed (but the ordering of the barplot is fine).
- Obviously the y-Axis (jurisdiction) seems to be ordered alphabetically, but I'd rather have this to be ordered manually (as in the tibble). Unfortunately I did not manage to get this fixed.

Thank you for any advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your two questions:

1. Add the argument `reverse = T` to your last line, changing it to: `guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Witnesses heard", reverse = T))`
2. Since you already suggested `forcats`, you can use `fct_relevel`: `temp2 <- temp2 %>% mutate(kt = fct_relevel(kt, "Berne"))`. Just specifying `"Berne"` will move it to the front. You could as well specify all levels, like `fct_relevel(kt, "Berne", "Basel", "Geneva", "Zurich")`, but this isn't necessary.

#### Full example

```r
temp2 <- gather(temp, ' ', val, -kt) %>% 
  mutate(kt = fct_relevel(kt, "Berne"))

# the following is just for convenience when plotting twice
layers <- list(
  geom_col(position = 'fill', color='darkgrey'),
  geom_text(aes(label = val), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), size=3),
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()),
  theme_bw(),
  labs(x='Jurisdiction', y='Percentage'),
  coord_flip(),
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.9, end = .5),
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Witnesses heard", reverse = T))
)

ggplot(temp2, aes(kt, val, fill = ` `)) +
  layers
```

[image]

In addition, you could use `fct_rev` to reverse the placement on the y-axis:

```r
ggplot(temp2, aes(fct_rev(kt), val, fill = ` `)) +
  layers
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
temp2 <- gather(temp, ' ', val, -kt)
temp2[,2] <- as.factor(temp2[[2]])
temp2[,2] <- factor(temp2$` `, levels = rev(levels(temp2$` `)))

temp2[,1] <- as.factor(temp2[[1]])
temp2[,1] <- factor(temp2$kt, levels = rev(levels(temp2$kt)))

ggplot(temp2, aes(kt, val, fill = ` `)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'fill', color='darkgrey') +
  geom_text(aes(label = val), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), size=3) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())+theme_bw()+
  labs(x='Jurisdiction', y='Percentage')+coord_flip()+ scale_fill_grey(start = 0.9, end = .5)+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Witnesses heard"))
```